# Calculate the length of the string and print from the middle of the string

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to perform the following but my code isn't working:

- Take a string from user input
- Calculate the length of the string and print from the middle of the string.

```
user_input = input("Enter a word: ")
x_user_input = str(user_input)
print(x_user_input[len(x_user_input)/2])
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you be more specific? If you're getting an error message what do you think it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the string from position the middle to the end you have to do the following:

```
user_input = input("Enter a word: ")
print(user_input[len(user_input)//2:])
```

Comment: *x_user_input = str(user_input)* is pointless as *user_input* is already a string

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying to do?

```
user_input = input("Enter a word: ")
print(user_input[len(user_input//2):])
```

Comment: @nonlinear Better would be *print(user_input[len(user_input)//2:])*

Comment: you are right, it would be faster and a bit cleaner